# Tag <a name> on portlet rendering in Websphere Portal

Tags: websphere, portlet, portal

I need an information about the portlet management in Websphere portal (6.1.5, but I think is the same for all versions)..
When the portal render a portlet, the html created has this structure:

`<td>`
**`<a name="7_SOMECHARANDNUMBERS"></a>`**

`<div class="wpsPortletBody"><portletapi:init/>.....`

I need to know what is the tag **`<a name="">`** and what is the element referred to the name attribute value.

Thanks!
Bye!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the portlet's identifier.  Portal generates a unique ID for each portlet that it renders on a page so that there's no namespace collision between portlets. See this link in the infocenter: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc_v6101/dev/wpsbsoutput.html